# How to run selenium script using remote action controls?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

We are using a tool for internal communication.So my question is how to run selenium script for the specific link.

For example- GMail log in and logout, If i enter email id manually on browser then email id should enter automatically on other browser, then i enter for password, so password should be enter and log in and so on.

Basically i need kind of remote operations on same machine for multiple browser.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After you execute the first operation in the first browser, you can write a simple TCP-IP agent where you can send him simple commands like create a screenshot. Or you can use automation framework like Telerik Test Studio where it is possible to connect to existing opened browser, I don't think that is possible with WebDriver.
Sikuli- http://www.sikuli.org/
Telerik Test Studio Framework - http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework